# Connect to Snowflake via Python Connector OKTA

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Anyone use the [Python Connector to connect to Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/python-connector-api.html#label-snowflake-connector-methods), specifically using  https://<your_okta_account_name>.okta.com (i.e. the URL endpoint for Okta) to authenticate through native Okta.? I keep getting the error below, but I know it is the correct password/username. I am able to login fine via 'external browser" (but not through cloud9, nor do I want to continue this way)

```
Failed to connect to DB: appfolio.snowflakecomputing.com:443. Incorrect username or password was specified.
```

I have the following variables set up and I know I have correct password/username so going a little crazy , anyone here have this issue?

```
authenticator = 'https://company.okta.com'
user='user.name@company.com',
password= "password",
account='company'
```

People are having the same error (with & without MFA) but no solution was posted on snowflakes community board: https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D50Z00009JJKZGSA5/unable-to-connect-to-snowflake-using-aws-lambda

Comment: Are you using Okta with MFA or not? Okta with MFA only works when **authenticator='externalbrowser'**. See [here](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/admin-security-fed-auth-use.html#using-sso-with-mfa)

Comment: @Sergiu No, I am not using OKTA with MFA. When I use authenticator='externalbrowser', that works fine but not inside AWS Cloud/9 , as well that is not the approach I want to use ( using external browser). Thank you for your response.

Comment: If all connection parameters are good, then this looks to me a connectivity issue. Are you sure you can reach the Snowflake URL from AWS Cloud/9? Are you able to run a **curl -Is https://appfolio.snowflakecomputing.com**? It should return **HTTP/1.1 301** and **Location: /console** if you can reach the URL.